# Accessing method of a class in an implementing class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a class, suppose `a.cpp`. In the private property of this class, I have a pointer to `b.cpp` and `c.cpp` where `b.cpp` is the implementation of a virtual interface class, lets call `d.cpp`. Also, in the private property of `c.cpp`, I have a pointer to the interface class, `d.cpp`.

I want to access one of the methods of class `a.cpp` in `b.cpp` class. How can I do that?

The example can be
ok, let me give some methods in the classes

```
class A{
private:
  B *_classB;
  C *_classC;
public:
  int add(int, int);
}
```

Now, the interface class is D
So, in class D, we have

```
class D{
public:
  virtual int mul(int, int) = 0;
}
```

Now, the class B is the implementation of interface class D
So, B looks like:

```
class B{
private:
   int first_num;
   int second_num;

public:
   virtual int mul(int a, int b);
}
```

and class C also has pointer to the interface class, so C looks like

```
class C{
private:
  D *_classD;
}
```

Now, I want to call the method int add(int, int) in class B.

Comment: You named a class `a.cpp`?

Comment: Some code showing the structure of your classes / inheritance would help explain your question a fair bit more than your question does at the moment

Comment: ohh sorry... the classes are a,b,c,d

Comment: Do you mean that your classes are in different source files or have you named your classes and interfaces with a .cpp extension?

Comment: the classes are A,B,C,D.
it was by mistake that i gave the filenames instead of class names

Comment: Desperately needs some code to follow. Maybe even a real world example as a,b,c and d are seriously ambiguous

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call a method on an instance of the class `a` from the `b` instance that that specific `a` instance has a pointer to? Or do you mean something else? Perhaps you could explain using code?

Comment: Do you use header-files at all? Do you have files called `a.hpp` or `a.h` or something similar? Do you use `#include "a.hpp"`? Do you have separate class declarations and definitions, or are they smudged together in the implementation (`.cpp`) file?

Comment: What names have you given the member variables?

Comment: Try updating the *question* rather than pasting code in a near-unreadable comment please.

Comment: yes i include the header files.

Comment: To use virtual functions you need inheritance. B should inherit D. Do you have that?

Comment: yes, i do the inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Since, A contains B and there is no other relation, you will need to keep a pointer to the owner A in class B

Comment: in the header of class A, I already include the class B. Now, I can not again include class A in class B, isn't it?

Comment: youc an forward declare A in B or vice versa since you are using pointers to declare members

Comment: Hi aamir,the compiler gives me error when I include class A inside class B

Comment: dont do #include, just forward declare A like Class A; before declaration of B

Comment: yup that works.. but it still does not allow me to access the method of class A as it is in the private property of class A.

Comment: in the code shown above add(int, int) is public, another way is to make B as friend of A, better consider redesigning, by using inheritance rather than composition if possible

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of class `A`, or you need to make `add` a static member function of `A`.

In other words, the `static` solution would be something like this:

```
class A
{
 ...
 static int add(int, int);
};
```

Then a call would look:

```
...
A::add(x, y);
...
```

Or:

```
class B{
private:
   int first_num;
   int second_num;

public:
   virtual int mul(int a, int b);
   int add(const A& a, int x, int y)
   {
        return a.add(x, y);
   }
}
```

From a function in A, it would look something like this:

```
void A::func(int x, int y)
{
     b->add(*this, x, y);
}
```

There are several other solutions too. But without more information on what your actual use-case is, this will probably be about as good as it gets.

Comment: Hi Mats,
I am sorry for a mistake. The add function is inside the private property of class A. How does it change the calling procedure from class B?

Comment: Then A must declare B as a friend, so that it can access private members of A.

Comment: Ahh okay. Then, do I create an object of class A in B and use it to access its private property?

Comment: Yes, that would be one solution. It really depends on what A and B actually represents, what is "right". How does the `B` and `A` objects relate to each other, and which creates which depends on what you are trying to do. Clearly, there is a `B` object inside `A`, so `A` must presumably exist for an `B` to be held inside it?

Comment: yes, a pointer to B is inside A.

Comment: Yes, so what is createing A and B, and how do the two get used? It's all a bit messy the way you describe it. Assuming that `A::add()` actually needs to know which `A` it belongs to, you need to have a reference (pointer) back to the original `A` inside `B` too. If any old A will do, then make it static, and use `A::add(...)`;

Answer (score 0):

You can either make an object of type A a data member of B, or you can make a pointer of A a data member of B. Because in the classes you have made, there are no relations between A and B. 
Unless you want to do inheritance which i think is not the issue here.